# Unity. Как сделать "тень" персонажа, что будет выполнять все его действия

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть игра - платформер. После прохождения локации нужно сделать , чтобы при следующем запуске этой локации помимо основного игрока по локации передвигалась его "тень" повторяющая предыдущий результат, т.е визуально.
Какие советы?
Изначально хотел сделать таймер, что будет запоминать действия и время. Но происходит задержка и он сбивается.

Answer (score 2):

> Изначально хотел сделать таймер, что будет запоминать действия и
>   время.

Фиксировать действия необходимо не в таймере, а в коде самих действий. Например, если при нажатии кнопки "вверх" происходит прыжок, то туда же необходимо добавить код, который зафиксирует время и действие.

Такой подход будет удобен для игр, где не изменяется окружение и нет случайных воздействий.

---

Более точное решение - фиксировать изменения вектора скорости (в зависимости от механики, возможно координат), что позволит всегда верно расположить воспроизводимый объект. В добавок фиксировать все действия, аналогично предыдущему подходу, для воспроизведения анимаций.

На основе этого решения возможно запоминать состояние каждого динамического объекта, получится полноценный replay.

Comment: Все так, как вы и сказали. Беда в том, что происходит непонятная задержка. В одном скрипте через краутину записывается в массив пар 
<время> <действиe> , который потом передается в объект тени, где в свою очередь включается своя краутина, что уже проверяет, совпало время - воспроизвести действие. Повторюсь беда в том, что происходит задержка в таймере. Он даже выводит один и тот же ключ (время), но все-равно запаздывает - почему так - не знаю. Возможно я где-то ошибся в коде. Краутина - самодельный таймер, можете погуглить, но могу объяснить и я

Comment: @кирилл моисеенков, покажи этот код. Думаю если записывать в масиив время прошедшее с последней записи, то потом можно в твоем coroutines юзать WaitForSeconds(время из массива). А в при записи вообще coroutines не нужен, нужно делать запись при нажатии на кнопки.